# Webforms vs Razor vs MVC and Industry Uses

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm pretty familiar with C# and web development, so I've decided to delve back into the world of developing aspx sites - after working in lamp for a few years now. Since I'm really only familiar with classic asp-era in MS terms, I have a few questions in terms of when to use which approach - and also some more insight on which might be favored in the industry.

I've seen these types of questions asked a few times, but couldn't find anything as specific as what I am looking for:

1. I realize ASP MVC is the major approach to developing robust web
   applications, but is this the correct approach even for simple,
   client websites that don't require much other than a clean and/or
   responsive design? If not, are web forms what I should be looking
   at?
2. Outside of focusing on a few sites I have to do (that I plan to do via ASPX), 
   what should I be focusing on to gain a more practical approach to showcase 
   my abilities with C#/ASP in order to obtain a junior/mid developer role working 
   with C#/.NET, etc.

*3. Almost forgot, any possible suggestions on some good books that apply to real-world scenarios using C# MVC, WPF, WCF, Razor, etc. would be helpful

Comment: it might be migrated to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory, ASP.NET Web Forms should be more suitable for rapid prototyping ie. quickly throwing somethnig together without really focusing on scalability and things like separation of concerns etcetera.

ASP.NET MVC on the other hand makes a better separation between the views and the logic and should be the way to go when you want to build large applications where separation of concerns and scalability is important.

That being said, personally I would never choose ASP.NET Web Forms, not even for a small project. I find that ASP.NET MVC is a much cleaner approach. To me Web Forms is just trying to force a desktop development model over HTTP, which is just a leaky abstraction as you will soon be trying to circumvent this model because it just doesn't fit. As for rapid prototyping, it's true that MVC doesn't have the quick Grid Views and elaborate controls, but personally I think you'll gain much more speed from having things well structured and separated not to mention a real HTTP-model.

As for other things you should focus on, I think apart from the server-side, client-side development is increasingly important. Apart from just plain JavaScript, jQuery is almost a must-have and lately SPA-frameworks such as AngularJS and Durandal are gaining a lot of traction. 
On the other side of the spectrum, there's the whole cloud idea which in certain cases requires specific knowledge. If you will be focusing on c#/.NET, I'd say take a look at Azure (you can get a free 90-day trial).
In between all of that there's a whole spectrum of different technologies that are worth knowing, but I would say start with what you need, invest time in some technologies and try to follow up on new technologies.

Just make sure you don't let yourself guided by buzzwords and focus on those technologies that actually help you solve a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with js, jquery and prototype as I've done a bulk of front-end work. I poked around with AngularJS a few times, but haven't quite seen what it is capable of yet. Right now though, I am trying to focus on the back-end stuff I am most comfortable with - and enjoy - since it seems that most of the jobs around here ask for MS-based development.

Comment: Another question: Should I be using MVC for these smaller sites or is it more suitable to do them with just razor?

Comment: I don't think it really matters that much. For a small site, just razor would do I suppose (although I have never used it sepeaately). My suggestion is, if you want to learn, go with MVC, it maybe a bit more difficult in the beginning, but you'll learn more.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely plan to work with MVC soon. However, I am tasked with making a gallery/photographer site and plan to use the MS stack. Just feel that MVC here might be overkill - although I will give it a try.

Comment: +1 Awesome answer, I was thinking about that and @Kenneth Answered my doubt.

Comment: +1 - nice summary. krosiris - for what it's worth, 3-4 years ago i *dreaded* mvc adoption as i was quite an expert in web forms. i saw all that *skill* as being lost. roll fwd 4 years and i would never dream of touching webforms and have used mvc exclusivley for all http based development since then. in fact, i review my antipahy at the time and kick myself at the amount of effort i could have saved, had i jumped into mvc and appreciated the benefits on offer. so in short, don't touch webforms, except as an excercise in futility and angst -avoid!!

Comment: Completely agree with this answer.  One comment though: `As for rapid prototyping, it's true that MVC doesn't have the quick Grid Views and elaborate controls`.  This will get easier as you work through more projects.  You'll end up creating your own utilities that will reduce this problem.  It's only tough in that first project, where you're trying to make sense of where everything fits.

Answer (score 1):

Only my Opinion but,

- MVC is fine for small, clean sites. On a like for like basis its typiucally cleaner than the ASPX equivalent (as it carries less state around and page sizes tend to be smaller). Being responsive is really down to the CSS and JS that you include.
- Firstly, focus on what you really enjoy, but take a look at some of the thinks like Angular JS or KnockoutJS and back end at things like IoC, Dependency Injection, Test Driven Development, Entity Framework and Azure.
- Just go through the various [Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/get-started) and [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) Content, examples and dev blogs on ASP.Net there is a mine of useful information there.

Comment: Why would you say MVC is fine for "small" sites? In my opinion, the bigger the site, the more benefit you'll get from its clean separation, not to mention it's ability to partition with Areas

Comment: I see a lot of sites that have the .aspx extension - does this mean they favored web forms over MVC? Could you provide insight as to why this might be?

Comment: They may be older sites and/or have been built by a company that has any number of reasons of doing so, such as the site was using this before any of the modern alternate where available, the established  team uses this approach, no MVC skill in house, etc ...  Actually if you take a close look you probably see far more sties that don't end in ASPX than do.

Comment: Really useful information, I'm going to experiment with MVC, but what I'd really like to know is why this would be the choice for a simple, 6-page site?

Comment: The count of pages doesn't really have anything to do with it. MVC does not impose any minimum limits on the size of site. in fact MVC has been used for everything from a single page Apps up.  http://www.codeuniquely.co.uk was built in just a few minutes using MVC. The code is very clean and lightweight, there was no real developer overhead to get it to work well on mobile devices. The choice of why is really up to you. I was a big ASPX fan but I've not worked on a single site in the last 4 years that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is more suitable for maintaining complex web application . if it is a simple web site i would not over kill it with IoC , Mocking , Web forms is more suitable for quick prototyping and RAD.

Comment: Thanks, I am beginning to understand more as I read, but I still don't understand why I would use an ASP MVC pattern for a simple 6 page site. If I were utilizing a database and doing some type of CRUD application, I would understand.

Comment: The default template you get in visual studio when you create an MVC app is a around 4 pages and super simple to edit / responsive / unobtrusive. SO for 6 pages, you could add the extras really quickly and as you don't have to throw all that extra NuGet stuff in (as its optional) it may be an idea way to cut your teeth - so to speak.. :)